# Add destination to drupal view field link

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, drupal-views, drupal-modules

How can I add a desintation to a custom edit link in a view field?

I have a field in my view where I've customized the field to render as a link. How do I add the current view's page to the link as a destination, so that when the person follows the link and fills in the form, they will be redirected back the same view page they were on? Needs to include the page number variable as well.

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the theme for a particular field and use PHP to render the link however you like. Get the view arguments from $_GET['q'] if you'd like to manipulate them.

Alternatively, 
 **drupal_get_destination**();  will give you the current page as "destination=myView/with/args" to append to the link.

Comment: Thanks @jason-smith. I was thinking that was probably the one way of doing it. I found this article post which helped: http://grayside.org/2010/09/how-override-views-field-template-module